# Solving a non-linear, coupled system of equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So, say I have
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = y \sqrt{x + y} \qquad \textrm{and} \qquad \frac{dy}{dt} = x \sqrt{x + y},$$
with initial conditions
$$x(0) = 1, \quad y(0) = 0 .$$
I have managed to solve for $y$ in terms of $x$: $y = \sqrt{x^2 - 1}$.

How would I proceed to solve for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, based on the given initial conditions?

Comment: Add both equations.

Comment: Please do not deface your own questions---all the more so after they have been answered.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, by eliminating $t$, you've already essentially shown that the trace of the solution is (at least part of) the right branch of the hyperbola $x^2 - y^2 = 1$---the only question is how fast the solution moves along the trace. Since that curve is parametrized by $x = \cosh \alpha, y = \sinh \alpha$, the desired parametrization has the form
$$x(t) = \cosh \alpha(t), \quad y(t) = \sinh \alpha(t)$$
for some function $\alpha(t)$. Substituting in the original equation gives a new separable i.v.p. in $\alpha$ alone:
$$\alpha'(t) = e^{\alpha(t) / 2} , \qquad \alpha(0) = 0.$$
We can solve explicitly for $\alpha$ as a function of $t$ and substitute to give $x$ and $y$ as explicit functions of $t$.

> $$\alpha(t) = 2 \log \left(\frac2{2 - t}\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Change variables via $$x := \frac12 (u + v), \qquad y := \frac12 (u - v),$$ so that the system partially decouples:
\begin{align}
u' &= u^{3 / 2} \\
v' &= -u^{1 / 2} v .
\end{align}
(Conveniently, the new system is defined on $\{u \geq 0\}$.) The first equation only involves $u$ and is separable. Substituting the solution to that equation in the second equation gives a separable equation in $v$ alone.